# Word for a politically corrupt world/universe

Tags: word-request

I am searching for a word that describes a politically corrupt world/universe in  particular an antonym to the word cosmos. I have searched thesaurus.com and came up with nothing. I have considered the word dystopian but discarded it as it does not imply being politically corrupt.

Comment: Please submit this to Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: The word *cosmos* does not imply a lack of corruption.  Are you really after an antonym?

Comment: A dystopia is as bad as society can get; it very much implies it's going to be politically immoral. I don't quite understand why you want an antonym to cosmos though?

Comment: I don't think there's an antonym to cosmos. The world/universe is called so because of the laws of nature; man had no hand in it.  On the other hand,  it's man who make it corrupt.  So you can say politically corrupt, anarchic. or chaotic world.

Comment: What would the opposite of *cosmos* even mean? Nothingness?

Comment: Maybe it's the Greek origin of the word that caused the confusion? "[kosmos: order, good order, orderly arrangement](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cosmos)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the reference is obscure nowadays, you could call your universe **a Tammany Hall**. For a more current term, **kleptocracy** certainly is widely used to refer to corrupt regimes.

And I agree with the comments: "cosmos" in no way implies lack of corruption.